# SWT Parent Composite grab hover event from every child

Tags: java, widget, swt, jface, composite

#### I have

- A SWT `Composite` containing other `Control`s, such as `Label`s, `Button`s, and other custom painted controls. All of this in a generic fashion.

#### I want

- To add `SWT.MouseEnter` and `SWT.MouseExit` listeners on the main composite, without the children picking up these events.

#### I don't want

- To [add the listeners recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7226876/1774643), because then I would have to [handle event cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401848/1774643) in each sub-control.
- To add a display filter.
- Other events being stopped from propagating to children (such as `SWT.MouseDown`)

#### I tried

- Recursive listeners on children. I hope for a better answer than this one; some sort of SWT configuration on the parent composite, perhaps?

Comment: You've got all the options I can think of in your "I don't want" section. Why do you not want to use a display filter?

Comment: @Baz It just feels... unsafe... and maybe a bit "dirty". Should I just add a filter and check for the main comp's bounds?

Comment: It all depends on the options you've got. I personally find it cleaner than adding a listener recursively. You could either check the bounds or get the widget from the listener and check if your composite is its ancestor. But I'm curious if someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: I use addFilter with the check for the widget having the composite as an ancestor in similar code for SWT.Gesture.